# Is there a difference between とろっとろ and とろとろ?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, onomatopoeia

Please help me understand what mean とろっとろ in this sentense「あのとろっとろの猫撫で声で」. May I translate とろっとろ like "looking sleepy" or it's meaning only "soft / runny"?

```
Person A: 悪い男か何人泣かしとんねん
あのとろっとろの猫なで声で
Person B: とろっとろ?
```

The way I understand it like "You are villain who is bringing people to tears with in such a sleepy sweetest voice". But I am not sure.

Comment: `悪い男か何人泣かしとんねん` <-- Is it not 悪い男**が** ? or maybe something like 「あの悪い男か。何人泣かしとんねん、...」?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「とろとろ」 in this context would mean "***melting***", "very soft", etc.

「とろっとろ」 is an emphatic form of 「とろとろ」.  That small 「っ」 for emphasis appears at different places in onomatopoeias, but that is another topic.  (We say, for instance, 「もっちもち」 ("sticky"), but not 「もちっもち」.)

> Person A: "Such a villain, he is.  How many women has he made cry?  With that sweet, melting purring voice!"
>
> Person B: "Melting?"

Comment: I agree that とろっとろ is simply emphasizing とろとろ and this is the point of the question. It's a kind of a creative expression: we don't formally use it. But I'm afraid it's not accurate to say とろとろ means "melting," but it's to describe food that is delicious and **almost like melting**.

Comment: @karlalou See here: https://search.yahoo.co.jp/search;_ylt=A2RA2Ctz9VVdgn8AydyJBtF7?p=%22melting+voice%22&fr=top_ga1_sa&ei=UTF-8&aq=-1&oq=%22melting+voice%22&at=&aa=&ai=KaXa6UXAR4WKR37yM4acuA&ts=11758

Comment: @karlalou The context was mentioned. In describing a 'voice', I don't see how 'melting' could be viewed as anything other than metaphorical. Your determination that it isn't accurate seems overly proscriptive. High-quality beef and fatty tuna that 'just melts in your mouth' would also seem to be wrong by your standards.

Comment: とろとろ and とろっとろ also mean sleepy and making someone sleepy. So とろっとろの猫なで声 may mean purring voice that makes them sleepy. I didn’t know this meaning though I’m Japanese. Your studying is at a high level.

Comment: とろとろ is used for very loose rather gel type things and Japanese distinguishes this from melting. We would say ステーキがとろけるようだ, or just とろける to exaggerate, but 溶けている is over exaggeration and sounds strange for ステーキ.

Comment: ^ karlalouさん、 l'électeur さんの回答の、`とろとろ in this context would mean "melting, ... "` と `With that sweet, melting purring voice!` の2か所で使われている "melting" は、「溶けている」という意味ではないのですが・・・。英語の "melt(ing)" という語には、「人の心を 解きほぐす・なごませる・ほろりとさせる(ような)」「(声などが)人の心を とろけさせる・うっとりさせる(ような)」といった意味があるのをご存じないでしょうか？　ですので、上の l'électeur さんの２文を和訳すると、「この文脈での『とろとろ』は、『ハートをとろけさせる/うっとりさせるような』、『とても優しい』といった意味になります。」「あの 甘い/優しい、ハートをとろけさせる/うっとりさせるような猫撫で声で！」のような意味になるのですが…